# When will Software Updater notify of 16.04 Xenial Xerus availability?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04, update-manager, notification

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04.04 LTS Trusty Tahr. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenia Xerus has been released but **Software Updater** so far has not notified me as it has other people, e.g.:

[image: image of Software Updater release notification]

Note that I am talking about just LongTerm Support releases, not intermediate releases like 15.10, such as some questions address.

The **Updater** settings should be allowing this notification to occur:

[image: Software Updater settings]

When will the 16.04 notification occur?

(If the setting for new versions is changed to "For any upgrade", the Software Updater dialogue offers Ubuntu 15.10. Why?)

Comment: When the first point release, i.e.,  16.04.1, is released.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. Mark your answer as accepted when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of questions similar to mine; obviously I didn't choose the correct keywords to find those questions initially. The answer is that **Software Updater** does not notify you of a new LTS upgrade until the first point release, e.g. 16.04.01 in the case of Xenial Xerus 16.04 LTS.

To save you the trouble of finding those questions (which mostly tell you how to edit a config file or use command switches in the **Terminal**), start the **Software Updater** GUI and make any necessary changes there.

Check **Software Updater** > **Settings** button > **Updates** tab – click the link in the question above. The 'Notify me of a new Ubuntu version' setting must be set to *For long-term support versions*. The other two settings will either show no notifications for any release, or for all releases, including development *or* LTS releases.